# Need help with Type 1 error and large number of chi squared results

Tags: hypothesis-testing, chi-squared-test, multiple-comparisons, type-i-and-ii-errors

I have a received comment for my research that addresses concern on the 'volume of null hypothesis test' being performed throughout my study and if any corrections are being done to account for 'an increased change of a false positive conclusion' (Type 1 error).

It also pointed out the large number of Chi-squared results.

As a beginner researcher I am quite confused about this point. How is the large number of chi-squared result related to type 1 error?

Anyone has an idea what should I check/correct?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! [This](https://xkcd.com/882/) classic cartoon might give you an idea of why it can be problematic to test over and over.

Comment: @Dave Wow! Thank you for providing great & easy-to-understand resource. So it could be just really out of coincidence. Is there a way to prove that the link between green jelly bean and acne (from the cartoon) is actually significant? Would chi-squared value be an indicator?

Comment: I cannot think of why a chi-squared test would apply to such a study, but the cartoon isn’t about any particular test. If you want to show the green jelly beans to have a link to acne, some kind of adjustment for the multiple tests could apply. Such adjustments are not straightforward.

Comment: @Dave I see. I guess those adjustments you mentioned are the corrections I should make. Would you mind providing me some examples of possible adjustments?

Comment: There are several methods to correct for multiple testing, you can find a list here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family-wise_error_rate#Controlling_procedures